# Listview display wrong image at wrong place when loading thumbnail image from web

Tags: android-listview, imageview, custom-adapter

I am using List view for displaying android files i.e. showing Folder and files from server.

When i start my activity, i can see the list on the screen, just as i want it. 
and I am getting data from server.
I want to show structure like

when there is image file need to show image thumbnail (I have thumbnail URL which is getting from server by default imageloader displaying default image icon until thumbnail is not available).

when there is other file type like audio,video..... or file need to show that icon.

and when I am showing list it shows proper icon for related files.
But the moment i try to start scrolling the and in background my thumbnail is loading from server and when from server I am getting image from server and showing that bitmap thumbnail it will displaying thumbnail bitmap in other file type like folder or music file icon due to view reusing of listview.
this misplace is happen when getting image from server.

any one can please suggest me to how to overcome this problem.
below is my getview() method of my listview.

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

```
ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
if(convertView == null){
    convertView = _inflate.inflate(R.layout.layout_list, null);
    viewHolder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    viewHolder.owner = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.owner);
    viewHolder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumb);
    convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
}else{
    viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}

HashMap<String, String> item = (HashMap<String, String>) getItem(position);

viewHolder.text.setText( item.get("poiName").toString() );
viewHolder.owner.setText( item.get("owner").toString() );

ImageView imageView = viewHolder.image;
imageView.setTag(item.get("thumbs"));

//Is type of file is picture then display thumbnail by using imagloader class
    if (genericDAO.sub_content_type.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.TYPE_PICTURE)) 
{

        String url = getTumbnalURL();
        viewHolder.image.setTag(genericDAO.id);
        viewHolder.image.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        mImageLoader.DisplayImage(id, url, mActivity,viewHolder.image);

     }
     else
     {
    //Display related file icon
         viewHolder.image.setImageResource(FileUtil.getImageRelatedToFileType(mcontext, sub_ext));
     }

return convertView;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

although this code is insufficient. What I understood from this code is, you are using lazy loading for images, and **mImageLoader** must be running thread, which is setting image to **viewHolder**. 
you can set imageInfo as tag in else part also.

....

else
     {

```
//Display related file icon
     viewHolder.image.setImageResource(FileUtil.getImageRelatedToFileType(mcontext, sub_ext));
     viewHolder.image.setTag(genericDAO.id);
 }
```

Inside ImageLoader, when new image is downloaded, just before you set new image to viewHolder please  check for correct tag.